# Converting mouse position functionality to work with touchscreen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, mouse

I'm developing in Unity, C#, and I have a bit of code that checks for player activity based on mouse position and it's working well but I'm needing to also check player activity on a touchscreen (not a mobile phone touchscreen, but a touchscreen attached to a pc). How should I modify the code that I have below to also work with touch?

```
    private void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("LastMousePosition", 0, _checkMousePositionTimingInterval);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _currentMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    void LastMousePosition()
    {
        _prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    void CheckPlayerIdle()
    {
        if (_currentMousePosition != _prevMousePosition)
            UserActive = true;
        else if (_currentMousePosition == _prevMousePosition)
            UserActive = false;
    }
```

Comment: Is it not working for the attached touch screen? What's not working exactly?

Comment: Well, I've got an inactivity timer that instantiates after a set amount of inactivity that counts down and resets the game. It works when using a mouse, but not with touch. I just assumed it wasn't registering position because it was looking for mouse activity and not touch activity

Comment: How about `Input.touches[0].position`?

Answer (score 0):

Well for touch you start your inactivity timer if you don't get any touch inputs and wait for x duration.
for eg:

```
private void Update()
{
  if(Input.touchCount == 0)
  {
    if(!checkingForInactivity)
    {
      checkingForInactivity = true;
      myRoutine = StartCoroutine(CheckForInactivity());
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if(checkingForInactivity) StopCoroutine(myRoutine);
  }
}

 Ienumrable CheckForInactivity()
 {
   yield new waitForSecond(3.0f);
   //user is inactive
 }
}
```

Comment: You do understand you are starting a coroutine every frame when there no touch on the screen? That's not a good thing. Also, this is not how to stop a coroutine. You need to store the reference then stop the reference. This is flawed in so many ways.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.